# Titanium for iOS Development on Windows Platform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, titanium

I have downloaded Titanium for Windows platform. After installing correctly... I found that it needs iOS SDK.. So from where should i get iOS SDK. Is Development of iOS possible in Windows platform..??  What are the steps for making my Hello World Example to run in Titanium on Windows platform for iOS.

I have refered some of the previous post like:

[Windows 7 Development Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242583/windows-7-development-platform) or 
[iOS and Android development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993059/ios-and-android-development-on-windows)

But still not able to get exact steps for making my example to run...??

Comment: Neither of those links really has anything to do with what you're asking.  A much better reference can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Comment: Also, did you read the [documentation for Titanium](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Module+Developer+Guide+for+iOS)? "To develop an iOS-based Module, you'll need all of the following basic prerequisites: 1) Intel-based Macintosh running OSX 10.5 or above 2) XCode 3.2 or above 3) iOS 4.0 SDK or above"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No its not possible. You need to install Titanium on MAC then you will be able to develop applications for iPhone and Android.

Comment: it sucks even more deeply when you realise that breakpoints don't work on the mac edition. do you need any more reasons why you should not use titanium....come on appcelerator.....

Answer (score 2):

Titanium doesn't creates an iOS app, it creates the Xcode project... so you must have a Mac, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to develop iOS applications on a Windows machine (except for Adobe AIR for iOS applications).  The SDK only works on a Mac.

If you are interested in Adobe AIR, see some examples here:

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/06/adobe-air-2-7-now-available-ios-apps-4x-faster.html

Comment: But one time the xcode project is created, the rest is to build that xcode project in a mac machine and publish the app, i mean, there are not develop time in mac machine. Is it this ok?