# Can Titanium Appcelerator be used for IOS App development in a Windows Machine

Tags: android, ios, titanium, hybrid-mobile-app

Sorry if this question looks naive. I have a requirement for a Hybrid Mobile App development requirement ( IOS and Android ) which is not much complex , but ona Windows Machine . After a research on comparing with a few tools/platforms ( Xamarin/PhoneGap/Titanium Appcelerator) came to a conclusion to pick Titanium which helps to compile to native code.

But after the installation of Appcelerator I found ( with a heartbreak ) that IOS sdks cannot be installed in a Windows Machine . When I further investigated got the previous SO link 
[Titanium for iOS Development on Windows Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982639/titanium-for-ios-development-on-windows-platform) 
which is bit older. Needs advise whether on any options to develop a Hybrid App with Titanium on a Windows machine. Appreciate your directions and help in advance.

Comment: Have u been able to get the idea from below answer?

Answer (score 1):

**First Short answer:**

No you cant compile iOS apps on windows machine.

**Now reason:**

The reason behind it is that titanium javascript code is ultimately converted to xcode project and xcode only works on mac machine and its not cross platform

Thanks

Comment: Yes , Wahhab got an idea. Was just waiting for some more alternate suggestions before accepting as an answer. Thanks

Comment: You can try to run mac OS on virtual machine.

Comment: Yes, Swanand , I would resort to as a last option since its terribly slow.